# XPATH - Partial labels with TD

Tags: selenium, xpath

Newbie to XPATH

I'm able to select a label where I know the full path:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=certificateDropList</td>
    <td>label=jake-mike-john</td>
</tr>
```

However, I want to be able to do a partial search, something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=certificateDropList</td> 
    <td>//td//label[contains(text(),'jake')]</td>

</tr>
```

But it's not working for me :-(

Comment: You're somehow conflating the XPath expression with the XML document, it seems. Why is the path expression inside a `td`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller it is from selenium IDE I suppose.

Comment: @alecxe I see. @Kevin Where is the `label` element exactly? Can you show it, too?

Comment: Thanks Guys. Yes - selenium throw firefox plugin. I can select a label using the full name like: '<td>label=jake-mike-john</td>' . I can also do a partial search using: '<td>//td[contains(text(), 'jake')]</td>' but I don't know how to combine the two to do use a partial label

Answer (score 0):

A `Select` element normally has `Option`s. You probably want something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=certificateDropList</td> 
    <td>//*[contains(@label,'jake')]</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this didn't work for me, I'm selecting a label so I wonder is there a way to incorporate this?

Comment: In that case you probably do not have a `select` element, only some AJAX to *look* like a select menu. We would need to see code to be able to help you.